# How to set a range of dates without date time picker to hide elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

i want to do a range of days but i don´t know how can do this.

I get the current day with this code :

```
var today = new Date();
                var dd = today.getDate();
                var mm = today.getMonth()+1; //January is 0!

                var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
                if(dd<10){
                    dd='0'+dd
                } 
                if(mm<10){
                    mm='0'+mm
                } 
                var today = dd+'/'+mm+'/'+yyyy;
```

But i don't know how can do the range of date, i think, i need to create new var:

```
var ddd = today.getDate()-3; //discount 3 days
```

This is my elements( div's), i have a lot of, i put 3 div:

```
<div class="container-a">
            <div class="container-b">
              <div class="container-c">
                  <table border="1"style="width:100%">
                    <tr>
                      <td width="220" height="100">
                        1
                      </td>
                      <td width="200">
                       <div id="container-d">
                        <span id="completed">
                          25/01/2016
                        </span>
                       </div>
                      </td>
                      <td width="300">
                        3
                      </td>
                      <td>
                        4
                      </td>
                       <td>
                        5
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                  </table>
                </div>
              <div class="color-lateral-no-posible">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="container-a">
            <div class="container-b">
              <div class="container-c">
                  <table border="1"style="width:100%">
                    <tr>
                      <td width="220" height="100">
                        1
                      </td>
                      <td width="200">
                       <div id="container-d">
                        <span id="completed">
                          24/01/2016
                        </span>
                       </div>
                      </td>
                      <td width="300">
                        3
                      </td>
                      <td>
                        4
                      </td>
                       <td>
                        5
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                  </table>
                </div>
              <div class="color-lateral-no-posible">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="container-a">
            <div class="container-b">
              <div class="container-c">
                  <table border="1"style="width:100%">
                    <tr>
                      <td width="220" height="100">
                        1
                      </td>
                      <td width="200">
                       <div id="container-d">
                        <span id="completed">
                          23/01/2016
                        </span>
                       </div>
                      </td>
                      <td width="300">
                        3
                      </td>
                      <td>
                        4
                      </td>
                       <td>
                        5
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                  </table>
                </div>
              <div class="color-lateral-no-posible">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="container-a">
            <div class="container-b">
              <div class="container-c">
                  <table border="1"style="width:100%">
                    <tr>
                      <td width="220" height="100">
                        1
                      </td>
                      <td width="200">
                       <div id="container-d">
                        <span id="completed">
                          13/01/2016
                        </span>
                       </div>
                      </td>
                      <td width="300">
                        3
                      </td>
                      <td>
                        4
                      </td>
                       <td>
                        5
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                  </table>
                </div>
              <div class="color-lateral-no-posible">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Hide what elements? There is no html shown in question. We can't help without a proper explanation of what you are trying to do beyond *"date range"* which can have numerous UI display approaches

Comment: Any element, i know about that for example <div id="aaBB></div> for that reason im not write the element, be cause i can hide the element with $("#aaBB).hide; but im sorry if i can write all the code that i want to do, and i dont want to use UI be cause the user can't set the range

Comment: Well we need more detail on what you need then because right now it;s not clear. As for adding days that's not hard to search for using `javascript date add days`. Also a good library if you are working with a lot of dates is [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/)

Comment: please add more details. Give an example date, and expected result (what part of the above html should be hidden)